# C Casting a variable of type double to a variable of type char when freeing memory

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc

While dealing with a library, in the provided example source code I found the following code:

```
x     = (double *) malloc (narcs  * sizeof (double));
dj    = (double *) malloc (narcs  * sizeof (double));
pi    = (double *) malloc (nnodes * sizeof (double));
slack = (double *) malloc (nnodes * sizeof (double));
```

I've found nothing special here but when freeing memory, the source code example does the following:

```
free_and_null ((char **) &x);
free_and_null ((char **) &dj);
free_and_null ((char **) &pi);
free_and_null ((char **) &slack);
```

The free_and_null code is:

```
static void
free_and_null (char **ptr)
{
    if ( *ptr != NULL ) {
    free (*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
    };
};
```

My question is not why, when freeing the memory previously allocated, it is done a casting to a char double pointer. My question is why this is done this way, using a custom function to free the memory and why it was chosen a `char **` as the argument of this function.

I know that certainly this question is happening because of my still limited knowledge of the C language, but anyway could anyone explain why this is done and if this is a good practice.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: Whether `char *` or `void *`, `free_and_null` is built on the assumption that all pointers have the same size and representation. It's sloppy. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Isn't `*(char**)(&x)=NULL` undefined behavior? (when x is `double*`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have to agree with you - that code is a bit weird.  There's no reason the author couldn't have used `void **` just as easily.

In addition, the `if (*ptr != NULL)` check is unnecessary, since `free(NULL)` is perfectly legal.  The `;` characters after the braces aren't necessary either.

A simpler version might look like this:

```
static void free_and_null(void **ptr)
{
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
}
```

The reason this function exists at all is to make sure that freed pointers are set to `NULL`, which is helpful for detecting use-after-free bugs and avoiding double-free bugs entirely.

Edit: As StarPilot suggests below, it's probably a good idea to check that `ptr` itself isn't NULL:

```
static void free_and_null(void **ptr)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        free(*ptr);
        *ptr = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that a lot of C code is still heavily influenced by earlier versions of C, not least the "early days" when K&R was the definition. So, although `free(NULL)` is now defined, that certainly wasn't guaranted behaviour, say, 20 years ago. The use of `void` constructs was also much less prevalent when I first learnt C, back in the dim and distant past. Or maybe my memory has faded.

Comment: I'd agree with that, except the return type of this function is `void`, so that points to something else going on.  I'm not sure when `free(NULL)` behaviour was standardized.

Comment: Actually, the code should be checking that `ptr` isn't `NULL`, rather than `*ptr`. If a `NULL` pointer is passed in and then the code tries to dereference it, fun can happen.

Comment: @StarPilot, that would be a good check, yes.  Can't happen given the examples shown by the OP, but a bit of safety never hurt.

Comment: I take it back. In the body, K&R says, "it is a ghastly error to free something not obtained by calling `malloc` or `calloc`." However, appendix B states, "`free` deallocates the space pointed to by `p`; it does nothing if `p` is `NULL`. `p` must be a pointer to 
space previously allocated by `calloc`, `malloc`, or `realloc`." Clearly my memory was driven by fear of sentence 1 rather than the reality of sentence 2.

Comment: Reference for those who like them: K&R - http://it.becs.ac.in/content/Digital_Library/book/C_ritchie_book.pdf;

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the extra level of indirection (`**`) is because this allows the author of free_and_null to set the pointer to NULL.  If they simply passed * or x they would have a copy of the pointer which is passed by value.

```
static void
free_and_null (char *ptr)
{
    if ( ptr != NULL ) {
    free (ptr);
//    *ptr = NULL; CAN'T DO THIS NOW
    };
};
```

It's not a bad idea to reset pointers to NULL after the allocated memory has been freed as it can help detect memory leaks.  I wouldn't follow the style of the author above exactly but I think this can help you understand the rationale.  As Carl points out `void **` would have been a more appropriate signature.  You often see C code where people use `char*` as a "generic" sort of pointer type - which is wrong, there's no good reason to use char in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, avoiding the pointer to pointer, would simply be:

```
void *free_and_null_back(void *p) {
    free(p);
    return NULL;
    }
```

Usage:

```
p = free_and_null(p);
```

Or, for `#define` fans:

```
#define free(p) free(p);(p)=null;
```

Obviously that comes with all the usual caveats about the dangers of #define ...